# What is the difference between keras.layer()(x) and keras.layer(x) in the functional API of keras?

Tags: keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I was wondering what the difference is between doing something like

```
dense = Dense(64)
x = dense(input)
```

and this

```
dense = Dense(64)(input)
```

Are these two notations equivalent?

Comment: Do they have a different function after execution?

Comment: @PooyaChavoshi I don't think so? I can use them interchangeably for my very simple models without noticing a difference.

Comment: This may be due to differences in the input arguments of the methods.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "this"?

Comment: Functionality between keras.layer()(x) and keras.layer(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFTER EDIT:

No, there is no difference, they generate the same exact model.

BEFORE EDIT:

From keras functional API documentation:

You create a new node in the graph of layers by calling a layer on this inputs object:

```
dense = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
```

In the code you posted there are no assignments.

Check how the model is connected with the plot method, a layer could exist but not be connected with the rest of the model.

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "my_first_model.png")
```

source:

https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: Thank you, I saw just now, I made an incomplete example.
I meant to ask, what is the difference between 
dense = Dense(64)
dense(input)

and just dense = Dense(64)(input)

Comment: with those assigments there are no differences, it's the same thing